# Select user id for every date in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to select user id for every date in excel. Tried doing this =IF(A2=A1,(IF(B2>=B1,E1+1,0))) but not getting the exact expected result

```
Input

user_id  date
10003   12/19/18
10003   12/19/18
10003   12/19/18
10003   12/19/18
10003   12/20/18
10003   12/22/18
10026   12/19/18
10067   12/18/18
10067   12/22/18
10067   12/22/18

Expected output

user_id  date
10003   12/19/18
10003   12/20/18
10003   12/22/18
10026   12/19/18
10067   12/18/18
10067   12/22/18
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) based on the input table.

Put the `user_id` and the `date` items in the `row` section of your pivot table.

Optionally,

- select “Classic layout” in the pivot table options (in my opinion, this gives a nicer view for this purpose);
- remove the total rows in the pivot table
- add the count of `date` in the value field to show the number of unique occurences of the `user_id` and `date` combinations